# NumPy random sampling using larger sample results in less unique elements than smaller sample

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

I'm trying to build a dataset for training a deep learning model that requires positive and negative sampling. For each input list, I randomly choose 3 elementa to be the positive samplea and k elements to be the negative sample from the rest of the vocabulary. For some reason, at the end, when I use k=16 negative samples for each positive, I get less unique elements than if I would've used k=4 and I'm not sure why that's the case since larger samples should obviously provide more coverage. Here's the code that I have doing the sampling (replace value of `num_neg` to change # of negatives sampled). I feel like I might be missing something obvious but haven't figured it out...

```
pos_map = {}
neg_map = {}
num_pos = 3
num_neg = 16

# vocab maps from id => integer index, reverse_map maps from integer index => id. vocab size is ~28k and stores all possible values of id
np.random.seed(2)
for ids in ids_list:
    encoded = [vocab[id_] for id_ in ids]
    target_positive_indices = np.random.choice(range(len(encoded)), size=num_pos, replace=False)
    for target_positive_index in target_positive_indices:
        pos = encoded[target_positive_index]
        if pos in pos_map:
            pos_map[pos] += 1
        else:
            pos_map[pos] = 1

        # perform negative sampling
        all_indices = np.arange(vocab_size)
        possible_negs = np.random.choice(range(len(all_indices)), size=num_neg * 3, replace=False)

        # some negatives chosen could be the same as positives or in the context, filter those out
        filtered_negs = np.setdiff1d(possible_negs, store_indexes)[:num_neg]
        for n in filtered_negs:
            neg = reverse_map[n]
            if neg in neg_map:
                neg_map[neg] += 1
            else:
                neg_map[neg] = 1
print(len(neg_map))
```

Result for num_neg=4: 15842

Result for num_neg=16: 13968

Comment: The way you're generating `filtered_negs`, it's going to skew heavily towards lower indexes, and I believe this effect will be greater as you increase `num_neg`.

Comment: hm why do you say that? I thought `np.setdiff1d` doesn't sort?